# Importing Grouped Report Data to Database

Tags: sql-server, database, import, ssis

My company receives data from a client that is unable to provide data in any direct format so we have to import several reports that are in a grouped layout like the one below.  We have to develop in house methods to ungroup the report and then import the data to get all of the data we need.  Currently a member on my team is using MS Access / VBA to generate the needed detail records but I want to move this to a server based and automated process.  We are using SQL Server 2008R2 for storage and I would like to use SSIS to accomplish the task.  Does anyone know of a way I can generate the detail records and import the data directly into SQL Server?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking how to ungroup the data in SQL Server?  How to import the MS Access into SQL using SSIS? How to import the original reports into SQL Server?  Please clarify.

Comment: I updated the question a bit.  I am looking for a method to generate the detail records programmatically and import them into SQL server.  I want to eliminate the MS Access component altogether.

Comment: This would be hard to do unless you can provide a sample of data as it is grouped and then a sample of ungrouped data.  Even then it might be hard to do unless we have the method of how data is currently ungrouped but hard to say if we need that till we see the data.  I'm unsure of what the image you attached represents. Also does the data come to you in a csv format or how? Can you provide these details?  Thanks

Comment: The data is provided to us in an .xlsx format. For the file in the image above, my team finds the date that the activity is being group on and adds it to the detail lines, then deletes the group header and footer to make it ready for import.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm - well you will definitely have to do some programmatic adjusting of the data set to add that group date to the detail line. I'm unsure of how you will be importing the xlsx but I would recommend first off just using a SSIS package and then doing the adjustments in a script task as the "best" way to do this. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-task-examples/working-with-excel-files-with-the-script-task) on how to handle Excel in SSIS Script tasks.

If you don't know SSIS or especially programming though, you're next best bet (in my opinion) is to just import the data into a staging table, do the manipulations with T-SQL and then insert that table into your main table.  I did a SQL Fiddle of this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00a4a/14).

```
CREATE TABLE ActivitySummary
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  activity_date date,
  activity varchar(100),
  paid_time decimal(5,2),
  unpaid_time decimal(5,2),
  total_time decimal(5,2)
)

CREATE TABLE ActivitySummary_STG
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  activity_date date,
  activity varchar(100),
  paid_time decimal(5,2),
  unpaid_time decimal(5,2),
  total_time decimal(5,2)
)
GO

-- Simulate import of Excel sheet into staging table
truncate table ActivitySummary_STG;
GO

INSERT INTO ActivitySummary_STG (activity_date, activity, paid_time, unpaid_time, total_time)
select '8/14/17',null,null,null,null 
UNION ALL
select null,'001 Lunch',0,4.4,4.4
UNION ALL
select null,'002 Break',4.2,0,4.2
UNION ALL
select null,'007 System Down',7.45,0,7.45
UNION ALL
select null,'019 End of Work Day',0.02,0,0.02
UNION ALL
select '8/15/17',null,null,null,null 
UNION ALL
select null,'001 Lunch',0,4.45,4.45
UNION ALL
select null,'002 Break',6.53,0,6.53
UNION ALL
select null,'007 System Down',0.51,0,0.51
UNION ALL
select null,'019 End of Work Day',0.02,0,0.02
GO

-- Code to massage data
declare @table_count int = (select COALESCE(count(id),0) from ActivitySummary_STG);
declare @counter int = 1;

declare @activity_date date,
        @current_date date;

WHILE (@table_count > 0 AND @counter <= @table_count)
BEGIN 
  select @activity_date = activity_date
  from ActivitySummary_STG
  where id = @counter;

  if (@activity_date is not null)
    BEGIN
      set @current_date = @activity_date;

      delete from ActivitySummary_STG
      where id = @counter;
    END
  else
    BEGIN
      update ActivitySummary_STG SET
        activity_date = @current_date
      where id = @counter;
    END

  set @counter += 1;
END

INSERT INTO ActivitySummary (activity_date, activity, paid_time, unpaid_time, total_time)
select activity_date, activity, paid_time, unpaid_time, total_time 
from ActivitySummary_STG;

truncate table ActivitySummary_STG;
GO

select * from ActivitySummary;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a script component.

Total Data Flow:

ExcelSource --> Script Component (Tranformation) --> Conditional Split --> SQL Destination

In script component:

Check accountSummary on InputColumns

Add ActivityDate as output column.

Open Script:

outside of your row processing.

Add:

```
public datetime dte;
```

inside row processing:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(Row.ActivitySummary.ToString()))
{dte=DateTime.Parse(Row.ActivitySummary.ToString());}
else
{Row.ActivityDate = dte;}
```

Then add a Conditional Split to remove null Activity Dates