# MS-Access SQL update values from "Value" to "*Value" in the same table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm new in access sql and I have problems with tryint to format data for inserts from one table into another.

I have a table that looks like this where the values with "2017" correspond to the code that surrounds them like

```
code
values
* code
```

because that's the output of a very old system.

```
+--------------+------------+----------+------+
|     Code     |    Date    |   Time   |  Qt  |
+--------------+------------+----------+------+
| D4D5F44G8    |            |          |      |
| 2017         | 15.08.2017 | 22:30:44 |  792 |
| 2017         | 15.08.2017 | 11:17:03 |   48 |
| 2017         | 15.08.2017 | 04:50:52 |  288 |
| * D4D5F44G8  |            |          |      |
| F45D7W8E9F   |            |          |      |
| 2017         | 15.08.2017 | 04:50:54 |  792 |
| * F45D7W8E9F |            |          |      |
+--------------+------------+----------+------+
```

And I'm trying to insert into another table values that take such code as the only value for code:

```
    +--------------+------------+----------+------+
    |     Code     |    Date    |   Time   |  Qt  |
    +--------------+------------+----------+------+
    | D4D5F44G8    | 15.08.2017 | 22:30:44 |  792 |
    | D4D5F44G8    | 15.08.2017 | 11:17:03 |   48 |
    | D4D5F44G8    | 15.08.2017 | 04:50:52 |  288 |
    | F45D7W8E9F   | 15.08.2017 | 04:50:54 |  792 |
    +--------------+------------+----------+------+
```

But I can't find anything like cross apply or to get rows between values that are almost the same in plain sql, let alone Access sql.

Is this possible by using Access SQL or should I try to do it with VBA Access by way of a series of functions? Even help with doing this in SQL Server can help, but it'd be better to do it in Access.

Any type of suggestion can help, I've been stuck in this for quite a while.

Once again english is not my first language so thanks for your patience with grammar.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a problem to your premise.  Which column did you even use to define the ordering in the input table?  Internally, Access knows nothing of the adjacent codes.

Comment: The table itself has no key values, it's created by the system when the process starts with the code, it then adds Qt depending on the time it calculated them and when the process stops, it closes it with the "*" and the code, and then starts another.
What I'm trying to say is that the table doesn't have any way to be ordered other than taking the values of "code" and matching them to "*code" with the "*" as a closer

Comment: Is there even a timestamp left behind?

Comment: There is no timestamp, it's imported from a .txt to access.

Comment: Then change your import process such that you include information which can associate a code with its true records.

Comment: The .txt is created at the end of the day, and by itself it's just plain text with those values separated with tabs, even the headers are added by the import process, so there is no way to get an identifier, but it would be awesome if I could get one.

Comment: Well, the import wizard in Access asks lets you add a primary key (it even does so by default), so obviously, there's a way to add an identifier (there are many, actually).

Comment: What is the SQL Server tag for? Is that your destination? If it is use SSIS and modify the question I answered yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716060/importing-grouped-report-data-to-database/45719484#45719484

Comment: The SQL Server tag was because If the query didn't exist in ms-access sql, I was going to throw everything away and fo it in SQL Server, but you're right, it's a little bit too much to have it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have solved this and your way is the best solution.

However, you initially asked for a possible SQL Server solution.  And you can do it without cursors by changing your data into XML and using the SQL XML functionality.  Like this:

```
DECLARE @xmlData as XML

SELECT @xmlData = cast(replace(replace(
(SELECT
(SELECT ('' + fx.[XMLString])
FROM (SELECT
   case when [Date] is null
           then
              case when substring([Code],1,1) = '*'
                      then
                         '</CodeTag>'
                      else
                         '<CodeTag><Code>' + [Code] + '</Code>'
              end
           else
              '<SubCode><Year>' + [Code] + '</Year><Date>' + [Date] + '</Date>
<Time>' + [Time] + '</Time><Qt>' + [Qt] + '</Qt></SubCode>'
   end as [XMLString]
FROM
   #tblYourTableHere) as fx
FOR XML PATH('')) as [txtString])
, '&gt;', '>'), '&lt;', '<') as xml)
```

You can also avoid the above code by formatting the imported data into XML as you import it.  But if you already have it in a table, you can just run the above code.

Then you can run that XML Code through this query to grab the nodes:

```
SELECT 
   cast(ct.xcode.query('data(Code)') as VarChar(max)) AS [Code]
   ,cast(st.xcode.query('data(Year)') as VarChar(max)) AS [Year]
   ,cast(st.xcode.query('data(Date)') as VarChar(max)) AS [Date]
   ,cast(st.xcode.query('data(Time)') as VarChar(max)) AS [Time]
   ,cast(st.xcode.query('data(Qt)') as VarChar(max)) AS [Qt]
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/CodeTag') ct(xcode)
   CROSS APPLY
   ct.xcode.nodes('./SubCode') AS st(xcode);
```

Not too difficult and it uses native SQL structures.

Comment: This is intersting, I've never used XML with SQLServer before. I'll play around with this for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it by using vba in ms-access, it was a lot easier than I thought, I forgot that there was an entire language behind access that I had access to. *bad dum tss*

This is what I used:

```
Function Format_LS()
On Error Resume Next
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim This_Code As String
Dim SQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "select * from US_Old where Code not alike '%*%'"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
This_Code = ""
Do While Not rs.EOF
  If rs("Code").Value <> Trim(Year(Date)) Then
    This_Code = rs("Code").Value
  Else
 SQL = "INSERT INTO US (Code, Date, Time, Qt) VALUES ('" + This_Code + "','" + rs("Date").Value + "','" + rs("Time").Value + "','" + rs("Qt").Value + "')"
 DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
 End If

 rs.MoveNext
End Function
```

It needs cleaning but it get's the job done. Thanks to everyone that tried to help and pointed out useful things to me.