# SSIS - Bundle Header and Detail in Same Sheet Excel Source - Need assistance in adding bundle ID to Bundle Detail Items

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am importing an excel workbook. One of the one sheet's - "Bundle" 
has the Header and Detail on the same sheet.

The problem I would like to solve.
The Bundle Header item has the **Bundle Config ID** the Bundle Details *does not* have the **Bundle Config ID**.

[Bundle Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvohN.png)

As per the Picture 
My question is: 
How can I Use SSIS to add the **Bundle Config ID** to the Base components of each bundle Header Line.

*I have highlighted in Green what I would like as a result*.

Some files contain many bundles - SSIS will need to take the Bundle Config ID and add to all bundle detail beneath until the next Bundle Header and then repeat.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You

Comment: How about an excel macro which populates the BundleConfigID with the last known value? There is no straight forward way to do this in SSIS, lots of script component logic wold be needed to achieve it in SSIS.

Comment: a very simple script component is needed. i'll post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh WOW ! I did it. my first C# code - Yay. haha so happy going to do a dance. 
Thanks to Keith for pointing me in the right direction.

So here is what I Did.

See [input and output columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjoM4.png)
See [C# Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVwxW.png)

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {

        //Row.F2OUTT = Row.F2;
        //var_Row = Row.F2;
        if (!Row.F2_IsNull)
    {
         var_Row = Row.F2;
    }

        if (Row.F2_IsNull)
        {
            Row.F2OUTT = var_Row;  
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar answer I posted before and should help you with your script component:

[Importing Grouped Report Data to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716060/importing-grouped-report-data-to-database/45719484#45719484)

Basically, figure out how to identify your header row and update the variable.

Comment: I am stuck i cannot get your code to work for my example. Could you update it to use my input column of F2 and output Column of F2_OUT?