# How to pass result of Conditional Split to variable?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I have a flat file and used conditional split to filter the record into a single row. For example, RecordType == "2" retrieves single row with record having multiple columns say A,B,C,D and E. I want to pass the result of Column C value to a variable. And then to use it to update the table like:

Update tablename
Set A = that variable
Where A is null

Could you please help me in find out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the variable but use a Ole DB Command object.

You set the connection.

Then add your SQL from above:
Update tablename Set A = ? Where A is null

The map to Col C.

However, what I might guess you are trying to do is add a column to your other record set that has the detail but no key.

I would use a script component to do this:

Similar to this example:
[Importing Grouped Report Data to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716060/importing-grouped-report-data-to-database/45719484#45719484)